# SQL Server: Remove rows with a different aggregate (where or having)

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions

I'm hoping to only show rows where the total hours for employee id & date is greater than 10. This would mean aggregating on only **Employee ID** and **date** in order to remove the row but still showing Project ID in the result.

In cognos it would look something like: `sum(Hours for Employee_ID, hoursdate) <= 10`

Example data

```
Employee_ID  |  Project_ID  |  date  |  hours
A            |  98uyt       |  2/1/20|   8
A            |  76xyg       |  2/1/20|   8
B            |  76xyg       |  2/3/20|   16
C            |  98uyt       |  2/4/20|   8
C            |  98uyt       |  2/5/20|   15
```

In the above example the fourth row would be removed because Employee ID C only has 8 hours total for 2/4/2020.

Result:

```
Employee_ID  |  Project_ID  |  date  |  hours
A            |  98uyt       |  2/1/20|   8
A            |  76xyg       |  2/1/20|   8
B            |  76xyg       |  2/3/20|   1a
C            |  98uyt       |  2/5/20|   15
```

Here is my code so far

```
SELECT        
        Employee_ID, 
        Project_ID, 
        date,
        sum(Hours)

FROM    dbo.forecast
WHERE   date > getdate()

GROUP BY Employee_ID, Project_ID, date
HAVING  sum(Hours)>= 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use what you have as a filter, then select all based on that filter. Here's an example using a CTE for the filter:

```
; WITH OverTime
AS (
    SELECT        
            Employee_ID, 
            date,
            sum(Hours)
    FROM    dbo.forecast
    WHERE   date > getdate()
    GROUP BY Employee_ID, date
    HAVING  sum(Hours)>= 10
    )
SELECT
        Employee_ID, 
        Project_ID, 
        date,
        Hours
FROM    dbo.forecast f
    INNER JOIN OverTime ot
        ON f.Employee_ID = ot.Employee_ID
        AND f.[date] = ot.[date]
    ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fun option using WITH TIES

**Example**

```
Select top 1 with ties *
 From  YourTable
 Order By case when sum(hours) over (partition by [Employee_ID],Date) >=10 then 1 else 2 end
```

**Returns**

```
Employee_ID Project_ID  date        hours
A           98uyt       2020-02-01  8
A           76xyg       2020-02-01  8
B           76xyg       2020-02-03  16
C           98uyt       2020-02-05  15
```